# Rails has_secure_password saves successfully but then gives nil password - validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bcrypt

I have a User model with `has_secure_password` and `validates :password, presence: true`.

then the following happens:

```
$ rails console

> u = User.create(name: 'user', password: 'password')
=> #<User id: ...
> u.password
=> 'password'
> u.save
=> true
> exit
```

then I run the console again and..

```
$ rails console
> u = User.find_by(name: 'user')
=> #<User id: ...
> u.password
=> nil
> u.valid?
=> false
```

I don't understand why the password becomes null after all went right the first time.
The same happens in the development app, I can log a user in with omniauth_google, a password is created with `SecureRandom.hex(15)`. When I try to logout and log the same user back in by omniauth the user is found but `user.valid?` gives a `false` because the :passowrd mysteriously became `nil`, compromising the log in.

here is the code for User, perhaps I se something wrong here?

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :notes
    has_many :goings
    has_many :cafes, through: :goings

    has_secure_password
    has_secure_password validations: false

    validates_uniqueness_of :name, {message: "%{value} name already exist"}
    validates :email, presence: { message: "%{attribute} must be given" }
  validates :password, presence: {
    message: 'You must enter a password'},
        length: {minimum: 2,
        message: 'Your password must contain at least 2 characters'
    }
    validates :name, presence: { message: "%{attribute} must be given" }

    def self.from_omniauth(response)
        User.find_or_create_by(uid: response[:uid], provider: response[:provider]) do |u|
            u.name = response[:info][:name]
            u.email = response[:info][:email]
            u.password = SecureRandom.hex(15)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: You are not supposed to be able to see the password, that's the whole point of this `has_secure_password`

Comment: but it shouldn't give `nil` if that was the problem, should give an encrypted version.
But I see your point, why do I get a password then? and why if I run `user.valid?` gives `false` and `user.error.message` tells me that a password wasn't given?

Comment: @Eyeslandic you were definitely right, the validation problem was due to my custom validations, with the validations set only on creation (`on: create`) as per solution the problem was solved. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is that with `has_secure_password`, `password` doesn't really exist as a persisted model attribute. It only exists to handle the original password for encryption; after that it is `password_digest` all the way (hence why `.password` returns `nil` on existing objects.

Rails itself 'cheats' on the validations, only validating presence and length of `password_digest` ([GitHub](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/404ad9e8acf8ab45ae2314050131a00e57e63b40/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L55)):

```rb
# This ensures the model has a password by checking whether the password_digest
# is present, so that this works with both new and existing records. However,
# when there is an error, the message is added to the password attribute instead
# so that the error message will make sense to the end-user.
validate do |record|
  record.errors.add(:password, :blank) unless record.password_digest.present?
end

validates_length_of :password, maximum: ActiveModel::SecurePassword::MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH_ALLOWED
```

Your custom validations work fine on initial creation when there is a clear-text password to validate. But after that, there isn't one, so your presence check fails (and your other checks are irrelevant). To fix, you can add `on: create` to your password validations so that they only run in the case of a new record.